# Adding text after variable in JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

```
var example = "Test" ;

$('button').click(function() {
 $('div').append(example);
});

<button>Whatever</button>
<div></div>
```

How can I add text after the variable `example` in the jQuery code?

In other words, in the jQuery code how can I add text (in this example: "blah") after the variable so the HTML code will appear like this

```
<div>Testblah</div>
```

Comment: I answered your question, but, anyway, I find SO isn't for that kind of simple things. Learning JavaScript and checking available string operators should be enough to get it...

Comment: do you know what do you want?? these answers are fine to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for,

```
$('div').html(example + "blah");
```

Note I have used [.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of .append. You can also use [.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) if you gonna insert plain text inside the div.

Above is just a plain javascript string concatenation. You should read about [String Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators)

Also the above doesn't change the value of var example. If you want the value to be changed then assign the result to the example and set the div html.

```
 example += 'blah';
 $('div').html(example);
```

Answer (score 2):

change to this :

```
var example = "Test" ;
$('button').click(function() {
  example=example+'blah';
 $('div').append(example);
});
```

or:

```
var example = "Test" ;
var exp="blah";
$('button').click(function() {
  example=example+exp;
 $('div').append(example);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('div').append(example + "blah");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using concat (Vanilla JS):

```js
var example = "Test"
//to concatenate:
example = example.concat("blah")
document.write(example)
//if you want a space:
example = example.concat(" blah")
document.write(example)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to name your div like this:

```
<div id="one"> </div>
```

and put the jQuery code like this

```
$('#one').html(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but is this a simple string concatenation?

```
var example = "Test";

$('button').click(function() {
 example += "blah"; // ????
 $('div').append(example);
});
```

Comment: @amnotiam Is this concatenating "blah" to "Test"? I got lost.

Comment: Ah you removed your comment... :(